# Calling Java Objects in C++ in Android NDK - What IDE to use?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to use C++ Code in my Android App, which I'm doing using NDK/JNI. I have to be able to use the Java Objects in C++. (Note: I am not using C++ methods in Java.)

My problem is with the IDE. I have the C++ code in a folder called 'jni' in the Android project. I have installed CDT in Eclipse. A HelloWorld C++ project works fine confirming that the CDT set up is fine.

What I do not know is how to run my C++ Code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your code and what is it meant to be doing?

Comment: @DrYap: The C++ code is meant to be some platform-independent code that does some serialization and deserialization of message packets. The Java code is the socket code that I'm using to send the messages to the transport. Hope this information provides enough detail.

Comment: So the data originated in Java, needs to be processed in C++ and then given back to Java?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need native method in you class with a signature such as

```
native void processData(byte[] data);
```

Then in your JNI code you will need a C function with the correct name

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_package_and_class_processData(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz, jobject data);
```

The [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javah.html) tool can help you get the right names to match your Java class. Now you are in native code and you have a reference to the class instance and to the byte array. You can access the data in the byte array using the JNI methods provided through the `JNIEnv` instance. The Android [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_sharing) page has some help on this, you should read the rest of this page too if you are new to JNI.

I have assumed that you will be modifying the data in the byte array but if you need to return it in a new byte array then check out the [functions available in `JNIEnv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html). Note: when using C++ you do not pass a `JNIEnv*` as the first parameter instead you call functions as `env->...`

This is not a problem with your IDE however if your project is not setup to build with the NDK then your code will not be built. I believe eclipse has some tools to help with adding the NDK build features.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right click on your project and under the android properties click on "Add native support". Follow the prompts to set up native support for your project.